# Unable to resolve DioError even after giving the internet permission in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to resolve the dioError in flutter. The application is perfectly running in web but in mobile phone giving the below issue. I have already given the internet permission still giving me the error. It is the chat app, first 2 hits it's working fine but after I hit for 3rd message it is giving me the dioError.

```
I/flutter (29700): have Error [null] => Data: null
    E/flutter (29700): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.receiveTimeout]: Receiving data timeout[5000ms]
    E/flutter (29700): Source stack:
    E/flutter (29700): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488)
    E/flutter (29700): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483)
    E/flutter (29700): #2      DioMixin.post (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:97)
    E/flutter (29700): #3      ChatGPT._completeText (package:chat_gpt_sdk/src/chat_gpt_api.dart:96)
    E/flutter (29700): #4      ChatGPT.onCompleteStream (package:chat_gpt_sdk/src/chat_gpt_api.dart:89)
    E/flutter (29700): #5      _ChatScreenState._sendMessage (package:gpt_ai_bot/chat_screen.dart:73)
    E/flutter (29700): #6      _ChatScreenState._buildTextComposer.<anonymous closure> (package:gpt_ai_bot/chat_screen.dart:112)
    E/flutter (29700): #7      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1072)
    E/flutter (29700): #8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253)
    E/flutter (29700): #9      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627)
    E/flutter (29700): #10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306)
    E/flutter (29700): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:239)
    E/flutter (29700): #12     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:615)
    E/flutter (29700): #13     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98)
    E/flutter (29700): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143)
    E/flutter (29700): #15     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:617)
    E/flutter (29700): #16     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141)
    E/flutter (29700): #17     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127)
    E/flutter (29700): #18     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:460)
    E/flutter (29700): #19     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440)
    E/flutter (29700): #20     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:337)
    E/flutter (29700): #21     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:395)
    E/flutter (29700): #22     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:357)
    E/flutter (29700): #23     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:314)
    E/flutter (29700): #24     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295)
    E/flutter (29700): #25     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:167)
    E/flutter (29700): #26     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:341)
    E/flutter (29700): #27     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94)
    E/flutter (29700):
    E/flutter (29700): #0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:643)
    E/flutter (29700): #1      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1658)
    E/flutter (29700): #2      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162)
    E/flutter (29700): #3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778)
    E/flutter (29700): #4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799)
    E/flutter (29700): #5      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574)
    E/flutter (29700): #6      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51)
    E/flutter (29700): #7      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:23)
    E/flutter (29700): #8      Future.any.onError (dart:async/future.dart:617)
    E/flutter (29700): #9      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1658)
    E/flutter (29700): #10     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162)
    E/flutter (29700): #11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778)
    E/flutter (29700): #12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799)
    E/flutter (29700): #13     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574)
    E/flutter (29700): #14     Future._chainForeignFuture.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:519)
    E/flutter (29700): #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40)
    E/flutter (29700): #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your receive timeout is 5 seconds. But your server is sometimes taking more than 5 seconds to send the response.

You can increase the receive timeout to a higher value such as 15 seconds.

```
var dio = Dio();

dio.options.baseUrl = 'https://www.example.com/api';
dio.options.connectTimeout = 5000; //5s
dio.options.receiveTimeout = 15000; //15s
```

or

```
var options = BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: 'https://www.example.com/api',
  connectTimeout: 5000, //5s
  receiveTimeout: 15000, //15s
);
Dio dio = Dio(options);
```